# Magit - How do I sync my feature branch with the latest master without checking out master?

Tags: magit, git

Here's what I am trying to do::

I have one project in one git repository. I've made some changes in master and created a spinoff branch (b s) called `my-feature`. Now I've finished my feature and would like to check it in. For checkin, I need to (fast-forward) merge my feature branch onto `master` and check in `master`. Normally I could do this with the awesome magit-merge-into (m i) feature). However by the time I am ready to push, master has changed, and I need to sync master with origin/master first before I merge my feature branch.

What is the best way to do this with Magit?

---

I'm guessing this is a common workflow for other developers as well. From the terminal I can do something like this from my feature branch to accomplish the above:

```
# On branch my-feature
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout -     # My feature branch
git rebase -       # master
# Verify changes
git checkout -     # master
git merge -        # my-feature
git push           # pushes master 
git branch -d my-feature
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to checkout a local copy of `master`.  You just need to fetch the current ref for the remote `origin/master` branch (assuming the appropriate remote is named `origin`), and then use that.

```
git checkout my-feature
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

Assuming that `origin/master` is set as the upstream branch for `my-feature` then in magit this would be:

- <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `my-feature`
- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>
- <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

If you need to configure a upstream remote in magit:

- <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> `origin/master`

Or alternatively you can use the "rebase elsewhere" option:

- <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> `origin/master`